# POST a form in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, post

I would like to POST a form in an iframe, generated like so:

My JS loads an iframe inside the page, adds a form to the iframe and submits the form. What I would like to happen is the iframe to load the result of that request. So, I would effectively like to post a form and render the result *inside the iframe*, without touching the parent (apart from putting the iframe up for display in the first place).

I am using the code from this answer:

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit/134003#134003)

but I can't get it to not reload the parent. I post the form, and instead of the iframe refreshing, the entire parent refreshes. I don't know why that is, since the url it's posting to is different and would at least redirect there.

Can anyone help me with this problem? I just want a post inside an iframe and only within the iframe, basically.

EDIT: After some more research, apparently the form is not being created properly. I'm using document.createElement("form") and then document.getElementById("my_iframe_id").appendChild(form) to append it, but it does not seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Correct, because you are creating the form node in the current document.

```
document.getElementById("my_iframe_id").contentWindow.document.createElement('form');
```

to create it inside the iframe.

Comment: I have gotten the iframe's document as you specified, and I have changed the code to create the form correctly, but the form still reloads the whole page... I also create the controls inside the iframe, what else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: when you create the form, you can see it in the iframe (using firebug or equivalent)? you could add .target = '_self' - but that's the default behavior so shouldn't matter.

Comment: You know, I don't! With firebug I only see the <html> tags in the iframe, but if I do innerHTML on the iframe I do see it... It's odd...

Comment: After some more experimentation, the form appears to be a child of the iframe, but not actually *inside* the iframe. That is, I can see it by manipulating the DOM with javascript, but not in the iframe itself...

Comment: so try adding it to the frame's body? `document.getElementById('my_iframe_id').contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(form);`

Answer (score 1):

It works now, part of it was that "document" was wrong, as Dan said, and the other part was that, when inserting into the iframe, one needs to use `document.getElementById(div).contentWindow.document.childNodes[0].appendChild(form)` rather than just `document.getElementById(div).innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this will help, but the answer you point at does not give the form a name/id. If you are trying to post the form with something like `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`, you might have a problem because your form doesn't have a name/id.

In the past, I've had trouble with form submission apparently submitting the wrong form when there are multiple forms on a page. In every case, giving the form a name/id and then getting the form by id and calling `submit()` seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: That didn't help with the whole page reloading, sadly, but thank you!